# Inserting multiple rows into database using ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: vb.net, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a personal ASP.NET Core MVC project. On my old web site there is a form where I use a stored procedure, then using code-behind (VB.Net) I can insert two records into the same table.

I am currently working to convert the whole to ASP.NET Core MVC. I find the whole CRUD process fairly straightforward but have hit an issue. I want to insert two rows of data using one form. I have two tables - **Accounts** and **Funds** (FK AccountId). I want the form to transfer fund from one account to another.
So one line of data should be

```
AccountId =1, Description ="Transfer", Date=05/06/2020, PaymentType=Transfer Out
```

and then

```
AccountId =2, Description ="Transfer", Date=05/06/2020, PaymentType=Transfer In
```

I think I have sorted out the view, but I am stuck with the code for the Post. I can probably get it to do one record but how do I do two?

This is what I have tried so far:

```
[HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("FromAccountId,ToAccountId,Date,Amount")] TransferViewModel fund)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                Fund saveFund = new Fund();
                _db.Attach(saveFund);
                saveFund.AccountId = fund.FromAccountId ;
                saveFund.Description = "Transfer out";
                saveFund.Date = fund.Date;
                saveFund.Amount = fund.Amount;
                saveFund.PaymentTypeId = 4;
                saveFund.CreatedBy = User.Identity.Name.ToString();
                saveFund.CreatedDate = DateTime.Now;
                await _db.SaveChangesAsync();
                {
                    saveFund.AccountId = fund.ToAccountId;
                    saveFund.Description = "Transfer in";
                    saveFund.Date = fund.Date;
                    saveFund.Amount = fund.Amount;
                    saveFund.PaymentTypeId = 8;
                    saveFund.CreatedBy = User.Identity.Name.ToString();
                    saveFund.CreatedDate = DateTime.Now;
                    await _db.SaveChangesAsync();
                }
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
            }
            ViewData["FromAccountId"] = new SelectList(_db.Account, "AccountId", "Name");
            ViewData["ToAccountId"] = new SelectList(_db.Account, "AccountId", "Name");
            return View(fund);
        }
```

This seems to have all the data but only saves the last record. I have added a simple view model so that I can separate the ToAccountId from the FromAccountId.

OK I think I have solved it:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("FromAccountId,ToAccountId,Date,Amount")] TransferViewModel fund)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)

            {
            Fund saveFund1 = new Fund();
                _db.Attach(saveFund1);
            {
                saveFund1.AccountId = fund.FromAccountId;
                saveFund1.Description = "Transfer out";
                saveFund1.Date = fund.Date;
                saveFund1.Amount = fund.Amount;
                saveFund1.PaymentTypeId = 4;
                saveFund1.CreatedBy = User.Identity.Name.ToString();
                saveFund1.CreatedDate = DateTime.Now;
            }
            Fund saveFund2 = new Fund();
                _db.Attach(saveFund2);
            {

                saveFund2.AccountId = fund.ToAccountId;
                saveFund2.Description = "Transfer in";
                saveFund2.Date = fund.Date;
                saveFund2.Amount = fund.Amount;
                saveFund2.PaymentTypeId = 8;
                saveFund2.CreatedBy = User.Identity.Name.ToString();
                saveFund2.CreatedDate = DateTime.Now;      
            }
            _db.Fund.Add(saveFund1);
            _db.Fund.Add(saveFund2);
            await _db.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }
        ViewData["FromAccountId"] = new SelectList(_db.Account, "AccountId", "Name");
        ViewData["ToAccountId"] = new SelectList(_db.Account, "AccountId", "Name");
        return View(fund);
    }
```

Anybody want to improve on this?

Comment: Please. add the code you use to INSERT Data into Database, in your question. What is your Database?

Comment: If you can do one, why can't you do two? I can't understand your question; it's like you're saying "I can probably write 'hello world" to the console, but how can I write 'hello world' and 'goodbye world' "

Comment: Getting data from the view to the controller and getting the data from the controller to the database are two completely separate operations and it's not clear which one you are actually having a problem with. You need to be clear about that in your own head first, then be clear in your description to us.